# AWS application migrations service MAC address?

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, migration, application

I want to migrate a on premise license server to aws using lift and shit of aws. There are couple of license server softwares running on server which are tied to MAC address of server. Software's are in production and are heavily used.
Is there a way I can retain MAC address of server from on premise to AWS or if I can manually assign MAC address to server after migration to aws?

Comment: I've used AWS for a while, and done a far bit of networking, but I've never heard of a way to transfer a MAC or set a MAC address manually. Transferring a MAC would defeat the purpose of unique MAC addresses. I think you're going to have to have the license transferred. Maybe someone else has another idea / solution though.

Comment: Given how unusual it is and how easy it is to test, you will need to validate this yourself. Changing a MAC address on Windows is fairly trivial though. You're only a PowerShell script away from that. There are a small number of vendors that have licensing based on combinations of factors such as MAC, but there are many other tags that are more suitable and difficult to change. The cloud isn't for everything yet